# Dropdown value lost after page reload

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Hi,

```
<select id="SelectLanguage" name="SelectLanguage" onchange="refreshpagehtml();">
<script type="text/javascript">
var PreferredLanguageValues = PreferredLanguageValues();  
var sel = document.getElementById('SelectLanguage');
for(var i = 0; i < PreferredLanguageValues.length; i++) {
var NameValuePair=PreferredLanguageValues[i].split(":");
var opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.innerHTML = NameValuePair[0];
opt.value = NameValuePair[1];
sel.appendChild(opt);
}
</script>
</select>
```

Using the above logic in the html page for the dropdown. The dropdown values are taken from PreferredLanguageValues() function from a JS file.

```
function PreferredLanguageValues()
{
var values = new Array();
//Add Language - Display:Language_CountryCode
values[1] = "English:en_US";
values[2] = "French:fr_FR";
values[3] = "Chinese:zh_CN";
values[4] = "Arabic:ar_SA";
values[5] = "Russian:ru_RU";
values[6] = "Spanish:es_ES";
values[7] = "Portugese:pt_BR";
return values;
}
```

The logic is such that when i change the dropdown value, the page is reloaded. The page   reloaded doesn't show the selected dropdown value. It always shows English in dropdown.
Could anyone please help me in this regard. 
Thanks.

Comment: How can you tell which language the user has selected?  Is it a query string parameter/cookie value?  Why is the list populated in JavaScript and not JSP?

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors:

1) Your array index **MUST START in 0**, if not, modify your for() to start in 1. This through an exception in the for because it attempts to do an split in an *undefined* object.

2) In the line:

```
var PreferredLanguageValues = PreferredLanguageValues();
```

you have an error, because you are naming both vars with the same name, change the name of the var or the function.

3) (Optional) Verify if you are declaring the function PreferredLanguageValues() before of the DOM elements are loaded because if the DOM element doesn't exist you will never see the options.

I make it work with this changes, i hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't need to be re-loading the page. Are you familiar with AJAX? This allows to 'query' your jsp page to get a list of values without re-loading the page.

Read an overview [here at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Or if I've missed the mark, please post the refreshpagehtml() function you're calling.

Comment: function refreshpagehtml(){ var Plang=document.getElementById("SelectLanguage").value; setCookie("localeCookie",Plang,0); alert("inside refresh "+ Plang); var path=window.location.pathname; var file=path.split("/"); var filename=file[file.length-1]; var contextroot=file[1]; alert("filename "+ filename); if( Plang=="en_US") window.location="/"+contextroot+"/"+filename; else window.location="/"+contextroot+"/"+Plang+"/"+filename; }

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason for reloading the page? You don't need to reload. If you want to reload the page then you may place the selected item in the cookies or HTML 5 local storage and retrieve them back and reset the dropdown selected value

Comment: I reckon the page is supposed to be reloaded in the chosen language.